# Selenium can't start IE8 on Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-rc

I have windows 7 32 bit and IE 8 32 bit. When I try to run the tests using *iexplore, I get a blank window. However, when I run the tests in XP and IE 7, the tests execute perfectly. Please see the image below.

[image]

Any remedies ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I solved this issue. The fact is In windows 7, it is not possible to run selenium tests in IE 8. However, there is a workaround. Go to IE 8, **Tools->Compatibility view Settings**
and then ***check*** the *Display all sites in compatibility view*.

Now if you type *iexplore in your code, it will run perfectly in the browser.

Hope this helps

Comment: It'll run the browser, but will it run it in IE8 mode or IE7 compatibility mode? They're quite different rendering engines, so if you're doing browser testing you need to know which one you're running.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried starting Selenium-RC server as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if you have Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx

Run all your IE below version 8 in a virtual machine instead!

Cheers,
Stefan